# PHP regular expressions: match several inclusion / exclusion rules for matches consisting of a complex character set

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Consider a collection of items. Each item may have no, one or many tags assigned. A tag name may consist of any valid unicode character except for whitespaces (space, newline, ...). The `tag` property of each item is a space-separated list of tags, e.g. `tag1 tag2 tag3`.

I am currently working on a PHP function that filters all items for those who does contain a certain set of tags, and on the other hand is not allowed to contain some others.

Currently, I generate a regular expression like

```
/^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)(?!.*\bbaz\b).*$/
```

out of the search query. This expression matches all `tag` properties which contains both, `foo` and `bar` but **not** `baz`. This works perfect while the tags start and end with a *word character*, but stop working otherwise (e.g. for tags starting or ending with a dot or hash sign) as the *word boundary* anchor only works for *word characters*.

Do you have any idea how I can modify the regular expression for tags like `.foo#`?

The solution should be supported on PHP 5.5+.

Comment: Should `.foo#` match `...foo#.%` or `abc.foo#def` or `(SPACES).foo#   `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are generating your pattern, If yes you can use a pattern like this:

```
/^(?=.*(\W|^)foo(\W|$))(?=.*(\W|^)bar(\W|$))(?!.*(\W|^)baz(\W|$)).*$/
```

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/QGB5zi/6)

If not you can simply get those characters outside the `\bfoo\b` like `\.\bfoo\b#`.

Answer (score 0):

A working example:

`^(?=.*(?<!\S)foo@(?!\S).*)(?!.*(?<!\S)_bar#(?!\S).*).*`

Instead of a word boundary I've asserted no white-space before and after the tag. A word boundary is a combination of two lookarounds; in this case you only want one of the two (twice).

- Flags: g, m
- Steps: 270

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dm9FAC/1)